# Finding longest flow path in multiple basins at once using ArcGIS Pro and Spatial Analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, watershed, basin

In my watershed I have around 400 basins. I need to find the max flow length in each basin. The "Flow Length" tool creates the flow length for the entire watershed, not for each individual basin.

Is there a way to clip the flow direction raster by using the basins or is there a better workflow?

I am using ArcGIS Pro and I have a Spatial Analyst license.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative workflow is to turn your stream network into a polyline dataset and your basins into polygons then its a simple Intersect. The Intersection will cut up the network and assign the basin ID. I would then run a summary statistics grouping by basin ID and summing length.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a tool in modelbuilder:

Add iterator: Iterate through features in ‘basin’ feature class:

Tool - Extract by mask (Input: DEM / 'basin' selection as feature mask / Output:%Name%_DEM)

Tool - Flow Length (Input: %Name%_DEM / Output: %Name%_FlowLength / 'Upstream')

Tool - Mosaic to New Raster (Input Rasters: all %Name%_DEMs)

Result would be a raster with flow lengths limited to the boundaries of each basin.